# How to use template for collecting function calls with different parameters if they don't matter?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I have a 3rd party library, which has a function requiring a callback function with the following signature:

```
typedef void (*callback1) (void *data, SomeObj *obj, const char *param0, const char *param1);
```

There is another function which has a slightly different callback signature:

```
typedef void (*callback2) (void *data, SomeObj *obj, void *extra);
```

Now, I don't care about the parameters, I only need the fact that the callback is *actually* being called, and I don't want to write two separate functions with the same content.

Can I solve this with `template` somehow?

I tried with the below syntaxes:

```
template<class... dontgiveas> void mycallback(const dontgiveas&... args);
template<class... dontgiveas> void mycallback(dontgiveas&... args);
template<class... dontgiveas> void mycallback(dontgiveas... args);
template<typename... dontgiveas> void mycallback(dontgiveas... args);
```

How can I make a single function in C++ which can be called with any number and type of parameters?

Normally, I would define two functions:

```
void mycallback1(void *data, SomeObj *obj, const char *param0, const char *param1);
void mycallback2(void *data, SomeObj *obj, void *extra);
```

And I have to pass these to the 3rd party library:

```
3rd_party_library_function_a(mycallback1);
3rd_party_library_function_b(mycallback2);
```

Comment: why dont you care about the arguments of the callbacks? At some point you will need to call them, no?

Comment: No, I don't need the arguments *at all*.

Comment: how will you call the callback? I dont understand what you want to do.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to write a single function that you can pass to this library that only registers the fact that the callback was called?

Comment: See my update pls, let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: As written, the two library callbacks have the same name (callback1)...

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: So you are trying to pass one function to both callbacks?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to pass the same function to both callbacks (in spite of those 2 callbacks have different argument requirements by 3rdparty)

Comment: `template<class... dontgiveas> void mycallback(dontgiveas... args)` works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01720fc14e781fe7)

Comment: Aaaah sillllly mistake.. 3rd party needs the function to be `static`.. so indeed `template<class... d> static void mycallback(d... args)` works. Sorry people.

Comment: @Daniel Are you trying to pass a class member function?  If so then yes, it needs to be static as member functions have a different calling convention.

Comment: Yup. that was the problem. One more thing. Can I omit `d` from here somehow? `template<class... d> static void mycallback(d... args)`

Comment: AFAIK, no.  You can get rid of `args` though if you're not going to use them like `template<class... d> static void mycallback(d...)`

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard [allows a function pointer to be explicitly casted to another function pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131019/). Though, *calling* a function via a casted pointer is technically *undefined behavior*, but since the callbacks in question are using a calling convention, `cdecl`, that does not require the *callee* to cleanup any passed parameters (at least in x86, not sure about x64), you should be able to get away with using a parameter-less function and cast it as needed, eg:

```cpp
void mycallback()
{
    cout << "callback called" << endl;
}
 
3rd_party_library_function_a(reinterpret_cast<callback1>(&mycallback));
3rd_party_library_function_b(reinterpret_cast<callback2>(&mycallback));
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ngapGS)

Answer (score 0):

With template, you might do:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void mycallback(void* data, SomeObj* obj, Ts...)
{
    // ...
}

// And then
3rd_party_library_function_a(&mycallback<const char*, const char*>);
3rd_party_library_function_b(&mycallback<void*>);
```

but simple

```
void mycallback(void* data, SomeObj* obj);
void mycallback1(void* data, SomeObj* obj, const char*, const char*) { mycallback(data, obj); }
void mycallback2(void* data, SomeObj* obj, void*) { mycallback(data, obj); }

// And then
3rd_party_library_function_a(&mycallback1);
3rd_party_library_function_b(&mycallback2);
```

seems to do the job.